# View the last query that execute in jaydata,websql

Tags: web-sql, jaydata

I am using the JayData and WebSql for my mobile application. And query data like below

```
_context.FoodLog.filter('it.DateTime == '+dateObj+'').toArray().then(function(foodLogs).....
```

I want to know is there anyway or method through which i get the last executed query

Scenario 
(In Code Igniter (PHP Framwork) ig we make query using active record class than we can get last executed query by using this `$this->db->last_query();` so how can i get in JayData)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in JayData, you can propose it here: http://jaydata.org/backlogs